# Can't read excel file in SheetJS, react

Tags: reactjs, sheetjs

I am very new to react and try to import excel file to browse in react.
I tried to use sheetJS but it didn't work due to below error message.

> TypeError: _fs.readFileSync is not a function

```
import React from 'react';
import XLSX from 'xlsx';

class Readfile extends React.Components {
...
  var filename = 'test.xlsx';
  var book = XLSX.readFile(filename);
...
```

Error seems to come from readFile function.
Is there any steps I missed to code? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

[xlsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) library has support for both browser & NodeJS. However, some specific functions only work in NodeJS.

`readFile` functions read files from the file system and you don't have access to the file system in the browser.

In the browser following options are available:

- [Browser download file (ajax)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx#parsing-workbooks)
- [Browser drag-and-drop](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx#parsing-workbooks)
- [Browser file upload form element](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx#parsing-workbooks)

---

For example, this file is available on https://example.com/test.xlsx, you can use the following snippet:

```js
var url = "https://example.com/test.xlsx";
 
/* set up async GET request */
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", url, true);
req.responseType = "arraybuffer";
 
req.onload = function(e) {
  var data = new Uint8Array(req.response);
  var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {type:"array"});
 
  /* DO SOMETHING WITH workbook HERE */
}
 
req.send();
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in my response and thanks @KiraLT !!